# Generics: Type should operate on another type but instead operates on a literal value for a declaration?

Tags: generics, f#, type-providers

**I am trying to understand the following syntax:**

```
type CarProvider = JsonProvider<JsonPath>
```

**Specifically:**

```
JsonProvider<JsonPath> // What is this actually doing?
```

**I would like to read this as:**

"Let there be a type called CarProvider that is essentially a JsonProvider type that operates on this specific string value (i.e. some file path)".

However, I thought that with generics, types operate on other types. In this case however, we have a type (JsonProvider) operating on a string value and not an actual type.

Can someone politely educate me on generics within F# based on the example syntax described above?

**Context:**

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let JsonPath = "http://localhost:48213/api/cars"

type CarProvider = JsonProvider<JsonPath>
```

Comment: What you're asking about are 'static parameters' for type providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at in you example is a [Type Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/) in action. The "static parameter" (the bit in the angled bracket) is a constant expression so that at design time the language can provide you with types from this input, "on the fly".

The syntax for Type Providers extend the syntax used for named types with generic type args, which is where I believe the confusion has come from. To be clear, this is not generics.

The way you have read the example as is absolutely correct. What's really cool about this type provider is that the IntelliSense you will get on this type will come from the JSON returned by HTTP API calls to the `JsonPath` you passed in, as you type.